# brunch - require function from other file don't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, brunch

I'm working in a brunch project.

I have two javascript files, let's say A.js and B.js

A.js:

```
 function replacer(key, value) {
    if (typeof value === 'number' && !isFinite(value)) {
        return String(value);
    }
    return value;
};
```

B.js:

```
atts = ...
json = JSON.stringify(atts, replacer);
```

In my html I do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        require('scripts/front/A');
        require('scripts/front/B');
</script>`
```

When javascript B is executed I got replacer is not defined.

It is possible to call functions from different files?

Comment: the 'require` syntax is only valid in the nodejs namespace. You should include your files like you would any regular js file.

Comment: @Swailem95 It's working those syntax. I work with bower and npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a.js

```
module.exports = function (key, value) {
if (typeof value === 'number' && !isFinite(value)) {
    return String(value);
}
return value;
};
```

In b.js: `var replacer = require('path/to/a.js');`